# How to use search filters with tweepy's search_users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

```py
users = api.search_users(f"{name} AND (car OR racing OR F1 OR driver OR {city})", count = 10)
```

I'm writing a small script to search for people on Twitter by keywords using tweepy and its `search_users` method, but I always get a blank response.

Maybe someone has encountered this, or knows how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter’s user search API does not support any of these kinds of filters or advanced searches, so Tweepy does not, either.